# Why don't I see my question on the main screen?

Tags: support, questions, homepage

Here's the question [What's going on (in the OS level) when I'm reading/writing a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869368/whats-going-on-in-the-os-level-when-im-reading-writing-a-file)

And I don't see it. I can open it from "my profile --> activity --> asked question" only.

I opened another browser and found it but now I don't see it again. It was asked 20 mins ago and has one answer already (i.e. I should be on the main screen, there are questions which weren't edited for 2 hours).

upd: after I added "fake" `java` tag I can see the question again. It looks definitely weird.

Comment: How can I prove that I realy don't see it?

Comment: A screenshot of the whole page would be good.

Comment: @drachenstern: hm.. how can I do it? the whole page is much bigger then the screen.

Comment: @drachenstern: I can save it's html-content

Comment: Yes I know, it was a bit tongue in cheek. However, I also ack this problem. I don't see it either. I would suggest it has something to do with the new display queries, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Your edit suggests it is directly related to the tags then, which is in keeping with the invisible tagging they've added to help focus the frontpage on questions that you care about.

Answer (score 2):

The front page algorithm is complicated and varies per user, and also is partially a random sampling.

We get 3,000 questions *per day* so .. well, do the math. :)

More detail at:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/